# IOS UITableView detecting touch below table - requires subclassing?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, touch-event

I'd like to be able to detect when a user taps below my UITableView's last row, but without negatively impacting the ability to scroll the table.  Is there a simpler way to do this than subclassing UITableView (i.e. overriding touchesBegan for the table)?

The reason I'd like to do this is:
When the table is empty (first time app is opened) or only has a few cells, all that space on the screen could be tapped on to invoke an Add method.

I've tried using a big, custom UIButton with no image (i.e. invisible) in a big tableview footer, however pressing the button impedes any scrolling, but you want scrolling once there's already a few cells.  I'm thinking I could remove the button from the footer once there's more than zero items in the table, but that doesn't do anything for me when there are a few items in the table already.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A tap gesture recognizer set on the tableView's footer has done the trick for me.  As advertised, it detects a tap, but passes through other gestures, like scrolling, to the UITableView just fine.

```
//In viewDidLoad 
//configure footerView with gesture recognizer
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                            initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTapOnFooter:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.footerView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[singleTap release];
self.tableView.tableFooterView = self.footerView;

//Later on, implement the corresponding method
- (IBAction) handleSingleTapOnFooter: (UIGestureRecognizer *) sender {
    NSLog(@"The footer was tapped!");
    // code to add an entry to the table here
}
```

The footerView is a UIView I created in my view controller's nib file, and attached to a UIView outlet in the view controller.

I suppose a better solution would be a tap gesture recognizer set on the UITableView itself, with code to identify if the location of the tap was after the last cell.  If I get around to trying that I will update.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an `UINavigationBar` as `tableHeaderView` to your `TableView`? The button on the right in the bar could be the NEW button.

```
UIBarButtonItem *newButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"NEW" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(newEntry)];
UINavigationItem *navi = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];
navi.title = @"my table title";
[navi setRightBarButtonItem:newButton];
UINavigationBar *bar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, widthOfMyTableview, heightOfRow)];
[bar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:navi]];

...

myTableView.tableHeaderView = bar;
[newButton release];
[navi release];
[bar release];
```

Comment: A navigation bar button for the Add function is definitely a good alternative/addition; however I'm holding out hope for a suggestion that can fulfill the original request.

Comment: You can try it with an UIControl subclass of your own. I still like a New button more, because it's more obvious how to add a new entry. In some of my tableviews (those without naviagtion bar) I put "- add new" as first entry into the datasource.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question so it should be a comment on the main thread instead.